# Can you bind FormBuilder controls to an object?

Tags: angular, ionic2

By using **[(ngModel)]** it is very easy to bind a control like **ion-input** to an attribute that is using two-way binding. But the moment i use the **FormBuilder** to create the form in order to get validation I find no obvious way to bind each control in the **formBuilder.group({...})** function to an object. Is it possible to automatically populate the UserModel class instance I have?

```
userData : UserModel;
userForm : FormGroup;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) 
{    
  this.userData = {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: ''
  };

  this.userForm = formBuilder.group({
    firstName: [this.userData.firstName, Validators.compose([Validators.maxLength(30), Validators.required])],
    lastName: [this.userData.lastName, Validators.compose([Validators.maxLength(30), Validators.required])]
  });
}
```

The reason I ask is that I find this rather "ugly" in order to get the data from the form into the actual object which I previously could bind its properties directly using [(ngModel)] :

```
submit() {
  this.userData = {
      firstName: this.userform.get('firstName').value,
      lastName: this.userform.get('lastName').value
    };
  // send data to service
}
```

Comment: I think you are looking for `this.userform.value` which will return a object with 2 properties `firstName` and `lastName` with their corresponding values. Exactly what you are doing with `userData`. You probably want to get rid of `userData` when using Reactiveforms.

Comment: Also, 'in order to get validation', you can have validation too with template driven forms.

Comment: Ah so it's likely possible to initialize the userData (of UserModel class) object directly by assigning it from this.userform.value?

Comment: Or get rid of userData and send directly this.userform.value to your service.

Comment: Ah yes that too. Although sometimes I need to set some more data in the object before.